# Apache localhost not finding files unless they are index files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, localhost, file-extension

Got a new PC and trying to set my environment up the same as my previous environment.

**root index loads the home page (index.php)**:

localhost/root/

**contact-us without file extension "file not found 404 redirects"**:

localhost/root/contact-us

**contact-us.php the file is found if I add the extension .php**:

localhost/root/contact-us.php

**Other index.php files work aswell such as**:

localhost/root/blog/
localhost/root/products/

e.g. root > blog > index

but root > blog > this-new-blog cannot be found.

Everything is working on the live version of the website, just can't get my local host to be working...

```
RewriteEngine On

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

# To internally rewrite /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# Redirect to www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R,L]

# Error redirects
ErrorDocument 400 https://www.mywebsite.com/error/bad-request
ErrorDocument 401 https://www.mywebsite.com/error/unauthorised
ErrorDocument 403 https://www.mywebsite.com/error/forbidden
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.mywebsite.com/error/file-not-found
ErrorDocument 500 https://www.mywebsite.com/error/internal-server-error
```

I have the above code in my .htaccess for removing .php which previously fixed this issue on my old PC...

Any ideas on what I need to do to get this working???

Comment: Is your Apache configured to read .htaccess files (`AccessFileName` directive), and is at least `AllowOverride FileInfo` set?

Comment: @CBroe i got to admit i'm not an expert with setting up the htaccess file. I currently have redirects to www. and also redirect to https some ErrorDocument redirects, and also the rules to remove the .php extension.

Comment: And these _are_ working? Show your full .htaccess then, please.

Comment: They are working in the live version of the site yes... and the ErrorDocument redirects are working locally as the pages that are not index are being redirected by them... also unless i turn off the redirect to https and www. they work locally also.

Comment: I checked my httpd.config and AccessFileName .htaccess

Comment: I have edited my question to show the full .htaccess file

Comment: www and HTTPS redirect should come first, before you do anything else. ErrorDocuments should have _relative_ URLs - absolute ones cause a redirect, but with a redirect you would lose the original 404 response code. (And for 401 it does not even make sense to specify an external URL.)

Comment: `^(.+?)/?$` - allowing that optional trailing slash for your suffix-less PHP scripts make little sense either - sure, you could request `foo/`, but then your RewriteCond before the rule will check if `foo/.php` exists, which it will most surely not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249621/discussion-between-jack-h-and-cbroe).

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but this updated htaccess code fixed my issue.

```
############ LIVE ONLY ############
#
# force WWW
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com [NC]
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# force HTTP to HTTPS
# RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R,L]
#
############ LIVE ONLY ############


RewriteEngine on
# remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

# To internally rewrite /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]


# Error redirects
ErrorDocument 400 https://www.mywebsite.com/error/bad-request
ErrorDocument 401 https://www.mywebsite.com/error/unauthorised
ErrorDocument 403 https://www.mywebsite.com/error/forbidden
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.mywebsite.com/error/file-not-found
ErrorDocument 500 https://www.mywebsite.com/error/internal-server-error
```

I added the remove trailing slash code and commented out the force to www and force to https requests while working locally.

And now i can view all of my pages with clean URLs.